# google transit integration with google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to find out list of all bus stops between two places using google map api.
I have all transit feeds , but i don't know how to work with that.
can anyone tell me the step by step process to work with google transit?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

There's a Google Transit official API, you can read about this here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TransitOptions

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TransitInformation

You must create a route for getting to this information:

```
  directionsService.route({ 'origin': initial_pos, 'destination': final_pos, 'travelMode':google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT}, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

    //Setting the map to display    
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    //Setting the direction panel
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));

    //Setting the transit layer if you need 
    var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
    transitLayer.setMap(map); 

    //Setting the directions response
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);      
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Google transit is not a part of google maps API and has no api of itself.** 
You could add request param **output=json** to the end of google transit request link and parse json, or even try parsing HTML itself.

Comment: First tell me how do you use google transit. Do you display it in iframe, on separate page? Give me detailed description of you're problem.

Comment: i have a form where we can input (lat, lng) of a place and a college or university, when i submit the form i should get the route map with number of bus stations and sub ways (http://www.mta.info/developers/download.html)

Comment: no, i think its not there in google. we can get the transit feed from mta.info/developers/download.html, Newyork bus transit feed is available there.But i don't know how to implement that in to my site

Comment: You have to get in the google transit partners program (unlikely if you dont't work for the government on some transit agency). Then you have to put transit feed on some public avaliable location and "tell" the google where to download it.

Comment: can you come on g talk o skype?

Comment: I am at the workpace right now so No I can't sorry. Is it still not working? Did you try to run the code from some other computer (same link you sent me)

Comment: actually, i am a beginner. so i dont know how to start,..the things which i can down load from that link is the exact feeds...but i dont know whats next...pls help me..

Comment: 1st go to google transit page and try some transit query (from station to station). So you'll see if data is already on the google.